# Android not displaying special characters

Tags: php, android, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I am passing a character from PHP to android. Character I am passing is **ó**.

I am passing it after doing URL encoding, as I am using GCM

But when I get the message on the phone it is displayed like this:

�

Is there any possible solution to solve this issue?

Comment: usually these problems arise from misunderstanding the importance of encoding matching... the accented o is encoded as...? and the phone expect the text encoded in...? (e.g. UTF-8 vs ISO Latin1 etc.)

Comment: try to read the date like that text = new String(data, "UTF-8");

Comment: Solved the issue by using utf8_encode($message);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by replacing

```
urlencode($message);
```

with

```
utf8_encode($message);
```